# Help :( Booting into Emergency Mode

Tags: boot, lubuntu

Nothing really changed on the machine. I did a few updates last night and restarted and it was fine. I only use the machine as a Plex/Mumble Server nothing more really and it worked fine for Plex after the reboot.

Today I tried LFTPing a few files from my seedbox when my mounted External (/home/videos) was throwing errors of not being accessible via LFTP, even then i could navigate through the folders no problem.

So i restarted and I got two errors.
One was TPM something which i just deactivated in Bios, that error has cleared.

I still have another error and I cannot boot into the OS!!

drm:intel_opregion_init [i915]] *ERROR* No ACPI video bus found
/dev/sda1: recovering journal
/dev/sda1: Clean 307097/15015936 files, 4305168/60045824 blocks

I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing. I tried one thing I found online...and idk if i messed it up worse:

"I had the same problem and it has been solved in this thread: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php … 6#p1246026
this.
Mar 21 07:00:49 e6600 kernel: Command line: root=/dev/disk/by-label/arch ro 4

remove the "4", the "ro" is unnecessary as well as it is the default."

Please help :/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue. I went into my fstab which honestly I hadnt touched in at least a week, and deleted my USB drive from it.

I then booted into ubuntu advanced options and ran the fscheck and the dpkg options, and then it booted fine!

I remapped my drive in fstab and noticed that "Videos" was Capitolized this time, when it was lowercase before...that's the only difference that I could see but it seemed to work!

Phew!